# Selecting specific nth-child elements of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I am trying to select a table form field that occurs at specific instances on the table regardless of how many entries exist:

```
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > form > input[type=text]:nth-child(2)
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(10) > td:nth-child(2) > form > input[type=text]:nth-child(2)
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(17) > td:nth-child(2) > form > input[type=text]:nth-child(2)
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(24) > td:nth-child(2) > form > input[type=text]:nth-child(2)
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(31) > td:nth-child(2) > form > input[type=text]:nth-child(2)
```

I then want to use that selected value to populate another field that occurs in the table in a similar manner:

```
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(13) > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(20) > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(27) > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]
body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(34) > td:nth-child(3) > input[type=text]
```

One way I am thinking this can be done is to iterate through the table, but it's not clear to me how to do this or if this is the best approach. I would prefer a solution that uses jQuery.

**EDIT:** I have found out how to select the 7th nth-child of the first/top set of values (currentQty) and assign to the second/bottom set of values (moveQty), but it is currently assigning the first value (e.g. `body > table:nth-child(10) > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > form > input[type=text]:nth-child(2)`) to all of the values of the second set instead of matching it up with the 7th nth-child of this second set.

It seems like I am not iterating through the table properly. This is what I currently have:

```
$("table").each(function() {
    var currentQty = $("tr:nth-child(7n+3) td:nth-child(2) form input[type=text]:nth-child(2)");
    var moveQty = $("tr:nth-child(7n+6) td:nth-child(3) input:nth-child(1)");
    $(moveQty).val($(currentQty).val());
});
```

Comment: just use $('table ').each(function(){console.log(this) //It will return table}); 
I hope it can be useful for looping.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'm stuck on how to iterate through the tr:nth-child elements to grab every 7th nth-child.

Comment: Hi, can you show html as well?

Comment: Micheal just use the index value inside the each like $('#list option').each(function(index){
  //do stuff
  console.log(index);
}); . SO here you can check the nth-child.